# How to disable a form based on a check box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form full of checkboxes and I would like to disable the form if a certain boxed is checked.  I will have this appear multiple times on my site and I was wondering if there is a better way than what I'm currently trying (which isn't working).  If I want to use this same disable function multiple times, should I create a class 'disable'? Thanks!

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#disabler_0').click(function()
    {

    $('[name*=form1]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    });

});
```

html

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="disabler" value="one" id="disabler_0" />
          one</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="disabler" value="two" id="disabler_1" />
          two</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="disabler" value="three" id="disabler_2" />
          three</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="disabler" value="four" id="disabler_3" />
          four</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="disabler" value="five" id="disabler_4" />
          five</label>
        <br />
      </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: When you say disable the form how will that appear to the user? Do you want an overlay? Just disable all the checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to disable a whole form, but every inner element on it:

There's a dummy **updated** example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/S2SxN/

**Updated**
The code should be adapted to your needs and turn it more usable because once you disabled the whole form, you can't enable it again:

```
$('#disabler_0').click(function() {
    var elements = $(this).closest('form').find('input, select textarea').not('#disabler_0');
    if(this.checked) {
        elements.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        elements.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay then, based on your response:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#disabler_0').click(function()
    {
      $('#form1 input[type="checkbox"]').not("#disabler_0").attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    });

});
```

This will disable all input elements of type checkbox that are children of the form.

Comment: this is good, but how do you keep the one check box active in case of a stray click?  will toggle instead of click work there?

Comment: @dzilla I updated the response to show how to achieve this using the .not() method, which removes a particular element from the set.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually disable a form, the `disable` attribute is only used for inputs.  What you want to do is something like this:

```
$("#form1").live("submit", function() {

    if ($("#disabler_0").is(":checked"))
        return false;

    return true;

});
```

This will not let the form submit when the check-box is checked.

**Edit** for the comment clarification, this will disable all the inputs and selects when the check-box is selected.

```
$('#disabler_0').live("click", function() {

    var form = $(this).parents("form");
    var inputs = $("input,select,textarea", form);
    inputs.attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: perhaps i'm phrasing this wrong with the disabled attribute.  i had this code written down somewhere before but i can't find it.  what i would like it if box "x" is checked, the rest of the boxes are grayed out and cannot be checked.  maybe that's what @onteria_ meant..

Answer (score -1):

this can be improvment:

```
$(function() {
    $('.disabler').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('form').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

by this code you dont need modify code for each form

Comment: You cannot set a `disabled` attribute on the form, it has to be on the inputs.

Comment: I know, I just try add some improvement

Answer (score -1):

You could put a class on all of the checkboxes that you want to disable the form and use this code:

```
$('input.disabler').click(function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    form.toggleClass('disabled', isChecked);
    if (isChecked)
         form.find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
});

$('#form1').bind('submit', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
         return false;
});
```

Comment: You cannot set a `disabled` attribute on the form, it has to be on the inputs.

Comment: @Nick That's true, have updated it now. Although it seems it's still not what's wanted.